# OpenID Connect trouble with moodle 3.9

Tags: office365, openid-connect, moodle

Im using moodle 3.9 and i use the openid connect plugin. I registered mi app in azure active directory and got client id and key. Ive configured also microsot office integration, but when i login i get this error:
Exception - Could not get app or system token. This is for the first time.

After one intent, i get this error: The existing token for this user does not contain a valid user ID. Please contact your administrator.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Reading the documentation for moodle, I understood that only version 3.7 has fix the problems into this OIDC with Microsoft.